# ImportError: cannot import name pubsub_v1

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to import Pubsub_v1 and bigquery from google.cloud module. I have installed it and pip freeze shows below :

```
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4
google-cloud-bigquery==0.26.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.27.0
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1==0.15.4
```

In my python script, i am importing the modules as below:

```
import os 
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1 
import time 
import json 
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

The script is throwing error as :

```
ImportError: cannot import name pubsub_v1
```

If i run $sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-pubsub then It is able to import pubsub but failing to import Bigquery. I need both modules. Can anybody please help ?

Comment: have you tried upgrading bigquery as well? currently we are at version 0.27.0.

Comment: Yes.Upgraded it and it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgraded the other google.cloud modules using

```
$sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
$sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
$sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-logging
```

It resolves the issue.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem, it happened to me because I installed google-cloud-pubsub before google-cloud so here is my advise :

```
sudo pip uninstall google-cloud-pubsub
sudo pip uninstall google-cloud
sudo pip install google-cloud
sudo pip install google-cloud-pubsub
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while trying the `pubsub` python library. I followed the below steps to resolve the issue:

Upgrade the pip library:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip3 install --ignore-installed PyYAML
pip3 install google-cloud-pubsub
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sudo pip install googleapis-common-protos`

It resolves the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

just this one solved my issue
the others were not useful

```
sudo pip3 install google-cloud-pubsub
```

Answer (score 0):

These were helpful to resolve the issue for python 3.x version: (I assumed the **pip3** has been installed)

`sudo pip3 install google-cloud-bigquery
sudo pip3 install google-cloud-pubsub
sudo apt-get upgrade`