# Locally fine but on app engine: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on a Python project using Google Cloud's pubsub.

In my Python file, there's the following import statement:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
```

Locally everything works as desired, but when I deploy it with:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

This error occurs on my app engine:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
>              at  (/srv/pubsub/pub.py:21)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name pubsub\_v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011713/importerror-cannot-import-name-pubsub-v1)

Comment: Did you declared the module on your requirements.txt file? Is so please share it with us

Comment: In my requirements.txt I only have declared Flask. Is it required to declare google modules there to make it work? I thought installing it in your env and deploying would be enough. @Chris32

Comment: Yes, just declare google-cloud-pubsub==1.1.0 and try again

Comment: Thank you @Chris32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the requirements.txt.
Generally developer test on local but forget to include the library in requirements.txt
App Engine will build the code in Cloud Build and will install dependencies listed in the requirements.txt metadata